# Google Sheet: Color scale conditional formatting works on column C but not on column B. Help me fix it?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Beginner here who just started building a spreadsheet to track different stocks.
I can't seem to get conditional formatting to work on certain columns.

Here's an example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1chW8URH3S4P_AGOfPr7oKmeqWApUWVBTwCgu0XtmuyA/edit#gid=0

Column C works fine, column B doesn't.

How can I get it to work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't working because the values in column B aren't numbers - although they look like numbers, they are actually text. You could try converting them to numbers like this - you need the Iferror because the hyphens will produce an error when it tries to convert them.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),,iferror(--SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://www.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&A2, "table", 8),"select Col4"),6),"*",""),"-"))
```